# Jquery mobile changepage with back button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 4 pages within my JQM main HTML file.  When I switch to one using changepage it's fine the first time, but I use a data-rel=back button to go back and this switches to the previous page but then bounces back to the page that has the back button.  Should I just not use data-rel=back?  If not what alternative is there?

Using JQM 1.3.1

```
$("#listView").on("vclick","li", function(e) {  
  //ajax call to get results for second page
  $.mobile.changePage('#second');
}
```

Button on second page

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
```

Comment: You could programmatically do this using $.mobile.back() as well..

Comment: I'll try it, I thought it would be the same thing though.

Comment: You might be right abt that but there's no harm in trying :-)

Comment: While you're adding the mobile.back fix try this as well : $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]').. Try to alert this out when you're clicking on that link.. This will tell you what your prev page is.. Then you could do a changePage to that page **if** mobile.back isn't working..

Comment: Weird thing is it works fine the first time.  Second choice from the list switches then breaks the back button.

Comment: Also try setting role : page when you're changing page to #second

Comment: I guess `data-rel=back` and `changePage` and conflicting. I recommend that you use `changePage` on back buttons as well, in order to eliminate any conflict.

Comment: Have you got your problem solved?

Comment: I found the real problem, I didn't have my click events loading in the right area.  I had them in $(document).on('pagecreate') I changed that to $(document).ready(...  So doing that data-rel=back works fine.

Comment: you shouldn't use `.ready()` with jQuery Mobile, stick to jQuery Mobile events only. http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: That's true, which one is usually used for adding click events?

Comment: such events work without assigning them to any other event. however you can `pageinit`, `pageshow`, `pagebeforeshow`.

Answer (score 2):

To go to previous page programmatically, use the below code. You need also to use `stopImmediatePropagation();` to stop jQuery Mobile from jumping twice, which will result showing the same page.

Edit: I tested it on iPad, `preventDefault()` is required too.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9fEza/)**

```
$(document).on('vclick', '[data-rel=back]', function (e) {
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 var back = $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]');
  $.mobile.changePage(back, { 
    transition: 'slide',
    reverse: true });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one. You can redirect between pages using location.hash=" " with page id in it.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/uJz3E/7/

```
$("#listView").on("vclick","li", function(e) {  
  // second is the page you want to redirect on click.
  location.hash = "second";
});
```