# Modify back button href in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to change the back button `link` in jQuery mobile depending on some circumstances. But the following approach is not working.

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('a[data-rel="back"]').attr('href',"#newPage");
```

In the console, its showing the new url but its not working. Also, can anyone tell the correct way to modify back button history in jQuery mobile?

Comment: in what event do u use this? `pageinit`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17045415/1771795 hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

You'll have to remove `data-rel` from the `a` tag if you want to redirect when you click on it because `data-rel` takes more priority that `href`. Here's how i got it to work.

- I have three pages, `#mypage1`, `animals`, `page3`
- On the `pagebeforeshow` of the second page, which has a back button, I put this code in, in which im changing the `href` to re-direct to `#page3` :

  ```
  $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#animals", function (e) {
     var $a = $.mobile.activePage.find('a[data-rel=back]');
     $a.attr("href", "#page3");
     $a.removeAttr("data-rel");
  });
  ```
- Beware that `pageinit` wont work in this case, because the `activePage` object will still point to older page.
- Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/rDtKL/2/

### Method 2 (a more better way)

Bind this event on the `a` with `data-rel` set to it. You can bind this in `pageinit` :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#animals", function (e) {
    $(this).on("click", "[data-rel=back]", function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $.mobile.changePage("#page3");
    });
});
```

Note that you must use **both** `stopImmediatePropagation` and `preventDefault` to make this work onclick.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/rDtKL/3/

### Method 3 (the most clean way there is)

Add that button to your `header` programmatically, so that you can decide whether you need that `data-rel` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id="backchange" to your button and change the text in jQuery :

$("#backchange .ui-btn-text").text("nextext");